# Removing blank column from dataframe not working, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I was deleting data frame columns if entire column has nan or blank values. Removing nan is working fine and assigning data[data == ''] = np.nan is not working under for loop.

```
for i in range(1, j):
    data = pd.DataFrame(dfs[i])
    data = data.dropna(axis=1, how='all') # Remove column if column has only nan values

    data[data == ''] = np.nan
    data = data.dropna(axis=1, how='all') # Remove column if column has only blank values
```

I updated code as per below comments but same issue.

```
data[data == ''] = np.nan
data = data.replace('', np.nan).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
data = data.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use, `replace`:

```
data = data.replace('', np.nan).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

Comment: thanks, but same issue, if I update manually, data = data.replace('', np.nan).dropna(axis=1, how='all'), then it will work. But in for loop it's not working, I was updating more than 300 dataframe.

Comment: You need to reassign dfs[i]  = data after your dropna.  You are modifying a copy of the dataframe in the list. So, I think you need to reassign back to your dataframe list.

Comment: I am not modifying the data in list, I assigned to df: data, then modifying it.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
You can also use `mask`

```
data.mask(data.astype(object).eq('')).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

But, because `bool('')` evaluates to `False` and if nothing else in the dataframe does, you could also

```
data.mask(data.astype(bool)).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

---

**Option 2**
Another way would be to

```
data[data.mask(df.astype(object).eq('')).notnull().any()]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,  TypeError: Could not compare [''] with block values

Comment: I threw in `astype(object)`.  That should fix it.

Comment: @faithon.gvr.py it is denpends on wether it is `''` or `' '`